# Observium > Cannot retrieve processor/memory data from host

Tags: monitoring, snmp, observium

I have successfully setup an Observium monitoring server on a AWS EC2 instance to monitor other EC2 instances running Ubuntu.

Hosts has been added successfully.

I can run

```
snmpwalk -v1 -c public 171.32.10.1
```

And get some output. In Observium dashboard, for each host I can see poller/system information, even data about Nginx status is working but nothing about:

- processor
- memory
- storage

Should I install or configure something to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was on other host side, by default, the SNMP client configuration gives basic information. You must edit /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf and be sure of:

```
 rocommunity public  default
```

That's it, I got plenty of data now!

I have written a small tutorial:

https://medium.com/@thomasdecaux/monitor-your-ec2-servers-with-observium-8851d2441aa1